# LINQ with if statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

My LINQ query returns values if "attribute" is bigger than 0 else it doesn't work and I get no error. 
I guess the && in the third line wants another statement which it doesn't get if "attribute" isn't bigger than 0. How can I get over this?

Edit: The code I've written first, was doing what abatishchev's answer is saying. I've tried to do a shorthand if statement without else but I've read about that wrong, so the code was meant to do something else then it actualy did. Thank you for the enlightenment on that matter but I still don't know how to implement my initial wish to linq, so I've rearranged the code to something that is nearer to my goal.

```
int attribute = 0;
var query = from x in db.Table1
            where x.ValueId == 1

            if(attribute > 0)
                x.Table2.Attribute == attribute

            select x;
```

If attribute is bigger than 0, then I wan't to add an additional where clause to my query.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If attribute is 0 then it should return an empty Enumeration.  What else would you expect?

Comment: What do you want to happen if attribute <= 0?
It's normal you don't get any results when attribute is 0, as the set of conditions in your where clause evaluates to false.

Comment: If attribute is <= 0 then I don't want the extra where clause in my query. The query with <= 0 should then look only like this: from x in db.Table1 where x.ValueId == 1 select x;

Comment: The behaviour you describe is exactly what the linq above is supposed to do. What is the goal expected ?

Comment: @ifsession, so you only want to apply your where filter when the attribute is greater than zero?

Comment: Please look at the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (attribute > 0)
   query = query.Where(a => a.Table2.Attribute == attribute);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
(attribute > 0) && x.Table2.Attribute == attribute
```

means 'if attribute is greater than 0 and table attribute is equal to given, otherwise skip'

```
attribute <= 0 || ((attribute > 0) && x.Table2.Attribute == attribute)
```

means 'if attribute is greater than 0 and table attribute is equal to given, otherwise include'

Comment: @ifsession: So, if attribute > 0 then compare, otherwise skip comparison, i.e. include record, right? Then my code will work for you.

Comment: @abatishchev: Your code returns a value if attribute is > 0 else I don't get any values, but I should. I've posted an answer that works. I'm sorry if my question was confusing. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to do this

```
int attribute = 0;
var query = from x in db.Table1
            where (attribute <= 0) ||
            (x.ValueId == 1 &&
            x.Table2.Attribute == attribute)
            select x;
```

That results in everything in Table1 when the attribute is <= 0.  If the attribute is greater than zero then it will apply your filters.

Answer (score 0):

If the attribute is *not* greater than 0, `attribute > 0` evaluates as false and because you use it in `where` filter, no `x` actually passes that filter and you get an empty enumeration, which is only correct. So the answer is review your logic, re-think what should the `attribute` mean and how should it affect the query outcome.